# ruby module works, but fails on rake test

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a ruby module which works as expected. However, when I attempt rake test, it fails on:

```
Error: test_directions(TestNAME) : NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for "north":String 

 /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/projects/ex48/lib/lexicon.rb:20:in 'scan' 

 /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/projects/ex48/tests/test_ex48.rb:7:in 'test_directions'


        4: class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase
        5:   
        6:   def test_directions()   
    =>  7:     assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"),[['direction', 'north']])
        8:     result = Lexicon.scan("north south east")
        9:     
       10:     assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
```

---

```
class Lexicon
 @sentence = []
 @direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']

def self.scan(words)
    words.each {|word|
      recognize = false
      if  @direction.include?(word) == true
        direction = ['direction', word]
        @sentence.push(direction)
        recognize = true
      end
    }
 end
end
```

Here is my test file:

```
require './lib/lexicon.rb'
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_directions()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"),[['direction', 'north']])
    result = Lexicon.scan("north south east")

    assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
          ['direction', 'south'],
          ['direction', 'east']])
  end
end
```

I have five additional tests for different arrays and conditions, and all six tests failed rake test. However, the code itself works as expected.

I edited the test file to send arrays rather than strings:

```
require './lib/lexicon.rb'
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_directions()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan(["north"]),[['direction', 'north']])
    result = Lexicon.scan(["north", "south", "east"])

    assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
          ['direction', 'south'],
          ['direction', 'east']])
  end
end
```

It still fails `rake test` on:

```
F
===============================================================================

>

  Failure: test_directions(TestNAME)
 /Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/projects/ex48/tests/test_ex48.rb:7:in
 `test_directions'
      4: class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase
      5:   
      6:   def test_directions()   =>  7:     assert_equal(Lexicon.scan(["north"]),[['direction', 'north']])
      8:     result = Lexicon.scan(["north", "south", "east"])
      9:     
     10:     assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'], <nil> expected but was <[["direction", "north"]]>

 diff: ?            nil           ? [["directio ", "north"]]
===============================================================================


 Finished in 0.009885 seconds.

 1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions,
 0 notifications 0% passed
```

Comment: The error appears even if one runs the code directly without the test file.

Comment: your `.scan` method doesn't return anything that is why you see `nil`. Check my answer once again.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.scan` method accepts array, not a string, so you should rewrite:

```
Lexicon.scan("north")
```

to

```
Lexicon.scan(["north"])
```

and

```
Lexicon.scan("north south east")
```

to

```
Lexicon.scan(["north", "south", "east"])
```

Moreover, I think you want to return a `@sentence` in this method according to your specs, so your method should look like:

```
  def self.scan(words)
    words.each do |word|
      recognize = false
      if  @direction.include?(word) == true
        direction = ['direction', word]
        @sentence.push(direction)
        recognize = true
      end
    end
    @sentence
  end
```

---

**Full working solution.**

I don't understand how you designed it, but in order for your tests to pass it should be:

**lexicon.rb**

```
class Lexicon
  @sentence = []
  @direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left', 'right', 'back']

  def self.scan(words)
    words.each do |word|
      recognize = false
      if  @direction.include?(word) == true
        direction = ['direction', word]
        @sentence.push(direction)
        recognize = true
      end
    end
    @sentence
  end
end
```

**test.rb**

```
require './lexicon.rb'
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_directions()
    assert_equal([['direction', 'north']], Lexicon.scan(["north"]))
    assert_equal(
      [['direction', 'north'], ['direction', 'north'], ['direction', 'south'], ['direction', 'east']],
      Lexicon.scan(["north", "south", "east"])
    )
  end
end
```

> Finished in 0.000901 seconds.
>   1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
>   100% passed

Comment: The variable words is an array, the result of a .split operation on a string.

Comment: I see that the test file was sending a string rather than an array. I attempted the correction that you suggested, but it still fails:

Comment: Failure:
test_directions(TestNAME)
/Users/antony1/Documents/Ruby/projects/ex48/tests/test_ex48.rb:7:in `test_directions'
      4: class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase
      5:   
      6:   def test_directions()
  =>  7:     assert_equal(Lexicon.scan(["north"]),[['direction', 'north']])
      8:     result = Lexicon.scan(["north", "south", "east"])
      9:     
     10:     assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
<nil> expected but was
<[["direction", "north"]]>

diff:
?            nil          
? [["directio ", "north"]]

Comment: @AntonySerio it won't work with a string in any way. Strings in ruby don't have `.each` method.

Comment: I converted the strings in the test file to arrays as you suggested. rake test still fails.

Comment: @AntonySerio please edit your answer with how you changed code, how you call the test suite(or how you execute it) and what results do you get

Comment: You are right. This was an assignment out of a book, 'Learn Ruby the hard way', where I was instructed to write a module to pass a particular test file. Once I looked up the specs for assert_equal, I realized that it was written backwards. I have no idea why the test file was written that way, or how it was expected to pass. I've looked up the online notes of other students learning through this book, and they had to re-write the test file as well.

Answer (score 0):

The method below accepts both arrays of terms as well as strings of terms delimited with spaces. It returns the list as expected by your test. It does not introduce senseless `recognize` local variable, that is not used by your original code anyway.

```
def self.scan(words)
  words = words.strip.split(/\s+/) if words.is_a?(String) # accept string
  @sentence |= words.inject([]) do |memo, word| # accumulate uniqs
    memo << ['direction', word] if @direction.include?(word)
    memo
  end
end
```

With this method your existing tests will pass.

Comment: Your code works differently from original version, where `@sentence` accumulates all the previous calls to `Lexicon.scan` method.

Comment: The method only needs to accept arrays. The variable words is an array, the result of a .split operation on a string. The local variable recognize is used in other tests.

Comment: Local variable `recognize` can not be used in other tests, since it’s scoped to `words.each` clause in your original code and is not even defined outside. You’ve tried to pass the string to `scan` function in your tests, that’s why I thought it makes sense to accept strings there.